Mixed effects clarification - Ecology
I have data from an experiment which measured a variety of response variables (e.g. soil carbon) across a number of sites each with one of 4 different treatments. These sites are all grouped within a similar landscape however each treatment is also grouped together i.e all sites for treatment A are in the same area, all sites from treatment B are in the same area but this area is distinct from treatment A etc.
In short it is a standard nested design of treatment - site - measurement (multiple per site)
Does it make sense to add site ID as a random effect in this case or are fixed effects of variables(e.g. ground vegetation diversity) which would account for the similarities/variation of these sites be more appropriate?
Mathematicallly the question would be:
y ~ x + b1 + b2 + ......
or
y ~ x + (1|plot_id)

"all sites for treatment A are in the same area, all sites from treatment B are in the same area but this area is distinct from treatment A etc." - so any treatment effect may well be confounded with the area!?

Yes, exactly - it´s an ecological study so "random" allocation of treatments in a standard nested block design wasn´t feasible

Do you have more than one observation per site ID? If not, you can't have a random effect for it, as the variation of the random effect cannot be told apart from the error term variation.

yes there are 6 observations per site ID - whcih could be each classed as a pseudo replicate of a any of the various measurements

With six observations per site I'd think a random effect for siteID will do the better job here, although the other idea with variables that characterise the sites could also be considered. I'd probably try out both and look at diagnostic plots to see whether one of them accounts better for variation within vs. between sites. It also depends on how many sites and how many variables that characterise them you have, and how well they characterise them. (Out of curiosity I'd probably even try out a model that has both, at least with a large enough number of sites. There may be identifiability issues, but I'd be interested in what happens.)
An important question is whether you are interested in the effect of the site-characterising variables, or whether you rather only toy around with them because you believe that they may give you a better model. I'd be keener on including them in the former case.
